How to resolve "No Java compiler was found to compile the generated source for the JSP" using JALIOS?
I have a problem concerning my Jalios application.
This is the problem:

"Exception in 'plugins/METZMETROPlugin/front/card/doCardPublicationCustom.jsp : No Java compiler was found to compile the generated source for the JSP [...] only a type can be imported. com.open.jaliosplugins.metzmetroplugin.utils.MetzMetroUtil resolves to a package"

I have to specify this is on a virtual machine and server, and in my local computer, everything works.
I tried so many things but still have this issue.
I tried to install Eclipse, to open my project and to change the Java Compiler; but it had no effect at all...
I have restarted my service million times.

Is this an error message from Eclipse or when running on your server outside of Eclipse? This sounds like a runtime problem, one that includes how the server itself was deployed and configured.


No Java compiler was found to compile the generated source for the JSP

You should run the server with JDK, not JRE. Only JDK has the Java compiler.
To solve this problem temporarily you can copy the file manually $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar from the JDK
to the common/lib directory of the web server.
